# running server socket infinitely

Tags: c, sockets

I am new to socket programming.Please provide me some techniques to run the server socket infinitely even if I close the client socket using close(clientfd) in C programming (the server has to wait in accept()for the next client connection even if the current connection is closed ). Also kindly help me how the close() in client side affects the socket in server side.

Comment: You need to work through some tutorials.  This isn't a focused question with a single answer.

Comment: yes, work thriugh some tutorials and then come back with detailed questions if you have any.

Comment: the book `TCP/IP Socket in C` provides good practical guide for this topic.

Comment: the accept() function returns a new socket.  having that socket closed by the client (and eventually the server) has no effect on the socket that the accept() function is using.  there are several good example programs online just google for them.  one critical item is the socket used by accept() needs to have the 'keepalive' option set

Comment: @user3629249 No, it doesn't need to have the 'keepalive' option set: and if you're going to make sweeping statements like that you need to provide a reason.

Comment: Is it a TCP or UDP or RAW socket?

Comment: possible duplicate of [running server socket continously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815537/running-server-socket-continously)