# running server socket continously

Tags: c, sockets

I have written code to establish connection between server and client using TCP socket.I have got problem in disconnecting the client side. I want server side to run continuously waiting for next client even if the current client closes.
My code for client side:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int sockfd = 0, n = 0,c;
char recvBuff[1024];
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
if(argc != 2)
{
    printf("\n Usage: %s <ip of server> \n",argv[0]);
    return 1;
} 

memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
    return 1;
} 

memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(6006); 

if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
{
    printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
    return 1;
} 

if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
   printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
   return 1;
} 
while(1)
{
printf("\n 1 to read \n");
printf("\n 2 to disconnect \n");        
printf("\n 3 to exit \n");
scanf("%d",&c);
    switch(c)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("\n Inside case 1 \n");
        if((n=send(sockfd,&c,sizeof(c),0))>0)
            printf("\n Sent \n");
        n = recv(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1,0);
        recvBuff[n] = 0;
            if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF)
            {
                    printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
            }
        break;
    case 2:
        close(sockfd);//to close only client not server 
    case 3:
        close(sockfd);
        exit(1);



    }
}

}
```

code for server side:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0,info,n;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

char sendBuff[1025];
time_t ticks; 
listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(6006); 

bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

listen(listenfd, 10); 

while(1)
{
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 
printf("\n Accepted \n");
while(1)
{
    printf("\n Inside while \n");
    if((n=recv(connfd,&info,sizeof(info),0))>0)
    printf("\n received \n");
    switch(info)
    {
    case 1:
            ticks = time(NULL);
            snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
            send(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff),0); 
        break;
    }
}
close(connfd);


 }

}
```

Provide me solution to disconnect client alone while server is running (server waits for next client connection). Even if I use return 0 in case 2 it does not works. Kindly help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Err, a thread? Have you looked at any tutorials?

Comment: I would urge you to investigate examples that use the `select` API to implement your server. And while you're there, please check for errors returned by the socket API calls because they do happen.

Comment: Possible follow-up of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812390/running-server-socket-infinitely .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if(n == 0)
{
   printf("client disconnected\n");
   close(connfd);
   break;
}
```

Add the above code in the server program next to

```
if((n=recv(connfd,&info,sizeof(info),0))>0)
    printf("\n received \n");
```

The problem is when your client going to disconnect, you need to send some api to close the client connection.

If the client has disconnected upnormally then above lines will used to close that client automatically.

Then the warning is made in `snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));`.